# Conversion failure using OPENQUERY from OLAP

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, openquery

I'm trying to retrieve some simple data from an SSAS cube using OPENQUERY in with an MDX string in SQL.

> Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "MSOLAP" for
>   linked server "OLAP_LIVE". Conversion failed because the data value
>   overflowed the data type used by the provider.

The query is simply:

```
select 
    StockCode = "[Product].[Stock Code].[Stock Code].[MEMBER_CAPTION]",
    LiveReturnPercent = "[Measures].[Live Return %]"

from openquery(
    My_OLAP_SERVER,
    'select
        non empty
        {
            [Measures].[Live Return %]
        }
        on columns,

        non empty
        {
            [Product].[Stock Code].allmembers
        }
        on rows

    from
        [Document DW]')
```

The error is occurring when transporting the data "before" it reaches the SQL - ie, I cannot resolve it by changing the third line to something like:

```
LiveReturnPercent = left("[Measures].[Live Return %]", 1)
```

As it still returns the same error. I don't know how to format / trim the query on the MDX side so it returns the measure as a shorter string.

If I run the MDX natively in SSAS it runs fine.

It appears that SSAS is internally defining a length for the `[Measures].[Live Return %]` string and then trying to pass back a longer string.

How can I resolve this?

Note that `[Live Return %]` returns a long floating value like `12.34632456` but I don't need that level of accuracy, so an answer that works by trimming it to `12.34` is adequate.

I also cannot modify the definition of the measure on the cube itself - not my cube; used widely elsewhere, etc etc.

**Edit:** I have also tried:

```
...
    LiveReturnPercent = "[Measures].[Live Return % Friendly]"

from openquery(
    My_OLAP_SERVER,
    'with member [Measures].[Live Return % Friendly] as
        [Measures].[Live Return %],
        FORMAT_STRING = "Percent"

    select
        non empty
        {
             [Measures].[Live Return % Friendly]
        }
        on columns,
...
```

but this also results in the same error - also with `FORMAT_STRING`s like `"#.##%"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to have been with `inf` values returning, as the measure is defined as:

```
[Measures].[Some Measure] / [Measures].[Some Other Measure]
```

Where `[Some Other Measure]` can be zero. A native mdx query neatly outputs `inf` in the resultset without erroring, but via openquery it seems to cause an overflow error.

I found that the `Divide` function returns `null` instead of `inf` so I was able to resolve this by changing the MDX to:

```
with member [Measures].[Live Return % NoInf] as
    Divide([Measures].[Some Measure], [Measures].[Some Other Measure])

select
    non empty
    {
        [Measures].[Live Return % NoInf]
    } 
    on columns,
...
```

Effectively calculating the same measure but to return `null` for `inf` values.

**Note that** this will return a slightly different result set to the original - the `non empty` will suppress the previously `inf` results as they are now `null`. This is perfectly fine for my purposes.